# Why am I getting this minitest error even though I never use minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

When I run my specs I get this error, even though I never include minitest anywhere in my code:

```
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
```

This is with rails 4 master.

here's the top of my spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

And here's the stack trace:

```
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/assertions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.0/lib/rspec/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in require'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-e5f5a838b96a/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `require'
  /Users/john/foobar/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of Minitest (built into Ruby) has had some breaking changes in relation to RSpec.

There is a github issue related to this issue here

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/772

Adding the minitest gem to your Gemfile is a temporary work around.

Another option would be to point to the github master version of rspec-rails as I believe it has been fixed there.

Comment: Minitest is bundled with `ruby 1.9` and above. `Rails` just piggybacks on what comes with `ruby`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my response.  I knew it was in Rails, but did not realize it was in core Ruby.  The rest of my response holds true though.

Comment: "Adding the minitest gem to your Gemfile is a temporary work around." — this won't make a difference because the minitest version is locked by rails to 4.2. I'm currently exploring using github master of rspec-rails, although the current version uses rspec 3.0pre, so it's a big jump. I'm trying to see if I can make all the pieces fit together...

Comment: I'm still getting this error in rspec-rails 3.0.0-beta. Any luck @JohnBachir ?